# Unclear Leibnitz's(?) rule, differential

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, curves

In the John Lee's book Introduction to smooth manifolds there is
an unlcear equation with three equalities (-2nd displayed formula on page 69)

$$\dot{\gamma}(t_0)f=d\gamma(\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t_0})f=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigg|_{t_0}(f\circ\gamma)$$ where I don't know how the first two equalities follow. Can someone give me a hint about the first and second =?

To look up the paragraph in the book, type

> john lee smooth 69 "tangent vector acts on functions"

into books.google.com

Comment: Prof Ted pretty much said it all. If you prefer reference from the book, its in p.55. With your case, the map is $\gamma : J \rightarrow M$. So its differential is $d\gamma_{t_0} : T_{t_0}J \rightarrow T_{\gamma(t_0)}M$, and your equality follow from definition of differential.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. For the first, $\gamma\colon (-t_0-\epsilon,t_0+\epsilon)\to M$ is a curve, and by definition $\dot\gamma(t_0)$ is the tangent vector to this curve at $t=t_0$, which is $d\gamma_{t_0}\big(\frac d{dt}\big)$ (i.e., the image under $d\gamma_{t_0}$ of the standard basis vector for $\Bbb R = T_{t_0}\Bbb R$.

The second is exactly how we interpret tangent vectors as differentiation along curves. If $v$ is the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma$ at $t=t_0$, then $v(f) = \frac d{dt}\big|_{t_0} f(\gamma(t)) = (f\circ\gamma)'(t_0)$.

Comment: I do not understand why if $v$ is the tangent vector to the curve $\gamma$ **then** $v(f) = \frac d{dt}\big|_{t_0} f(\gamma(t))$?

Comment: Because $v(f)$ is by definition the directional derivative of $f$ at $p$ in the direction of $v$, i.e., $df_p(v)$.

Comment: But how did we use that $v$ is the tagnet vector to the curve $\gamma$ to yield $v(f) = \frac d{dt}\big|_{t_0} f(\gamma(t))$?

Comment: Chain rule. $(f\circ\gamma)'(t_0) = df_{\gamma(t_0)}(\gamma'(t_0))$.