# Making sense of a derivative on direct sum

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, direct-sum

Consider $\mathbb{R}^n=E(t)\bigoplus F(t) $ be a continuous splitting. Is that possible to define a derivative on the direct sum such that
$$
(x(t)\bigoplus y(t))'=x'(t)\bigoplus y'(t)
$$
The reason being I was looking at the Lyapunov exponent where you can have such nice splitting. However most studies are done on the assumption that there is a direct product $\mathbb{R}^n=E(t)\times F(t)$. It makes some applications much more difficult. I understand that in finite dimensional space they are equivalent and my feeling of why people preferring direct product over direct sum is because it makes it hard to make sense of the dynamical system on the direct sum. i.e. what do you mean by
$$
x'(t)\bigoplus y'(t)=(x(t)\bigoplus y(t))'=A(t)(x(t)\bigoplus y(t))=A(t)x(t)\bigoplus A(t)y(t)
$$
I think the problem with the first equation is that
$$
x'(t)=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{x(t+\epsilon)-x(t)}{\epsilon}.
$$
and $x(t+\epsilon)\in E(t+\epsilon)$ but not $E(t)$. Thus we do not know that $x'(t)\in E(t)$ and therefore it might not make sense to write $x'(t)\bigoplus y'(t)$. Is the continuity of $E(t)$ makes the first equation true?

Comment: I suggest that you compare with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2484484/manifold-smooth-curve-differentiation, really it is the same problem.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. But looks like the problem you mentioned is looking for a collection of vector field when evaluating by the cotangent vector $d_{x^\alpha}$ resulting exactly 1. The result would be $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\alpha}+\sum_{\beta\neq \alpha} c_\beta\frac{\partial}{\partial x^\beta}$.

While here I am just asking that is the continuity of $E(t)$ enough so that $x'(t)\in E(t)$ and we can just treat the derivative separately on each subspaces. We want the result hold for all vector field (maybe whenever $E(t)$ is continuous).

Comment: I leave it to you to understand the differences. But taking into consideration what I mentioned, do you believe that continuity is sufficient? Note that Brin showed that the Lyapunov subbundles are always Hölder continuous but in general not more than that.

Comment: Yeah I think talking about differential equation on the notion of direct sum is a bad idea. $x'(t)$ is most likely to be perpendicular to $E(t)$ instead of in $E(t)$. However another alternative: we can consider the transition operator $\Phi_e(t,s):E(s)\to E(t)$. and so $x'(s)=\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_e(t,s)x(s)$. Now it makes perfect sense to talk about $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_e(t,s)=A(t)\Phi_e(t,s)$.

Comment: That's a good idea, but note that the derivative $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_c(t,s)$ doesn't make sense in general, for similar reasons. You need to compute the derivative on the whole space and consider then the operator $\Phi_c(t,s)$ applied to some vector in $E(s)$. So really $\frac{d}{dt}\Phi(t,s)v=A(t)\Phi(t,s)v$. A similar comment can be made for a cocycle.

Comment: Good point there. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for @John B, the answer is 'NO' and talking about differential equation on the notion of direct sum is a bad idea (No wonder people are avoiding it). $x′(t)$ is most likely to be perpendicular to $E(t)$ instead of in $E(t)$.

However another alternative: we can consider the transition operator $\Phi(t,s)=\Phi_e(t,s)+\Phi_u(t,s)$ where $\Phi_e(t,s):E(s)\to E(t)$, $\Phi_u(t,s):F(s)\to F(t)$ and maps everything else to 0. Now we just need to observe that
$$\frac{d}{dt}(x(t)\bigoplus y(t))=\frac{d}{dt}(\Phi(t,0)x_0\bigoplus \Phi(t,0)y_0)=A(t)\Phi(t,0)x_0+A(t)\Phi(t,0)y_0=A(t)(\Phi(t,0)x_0\bigoplus \Phi(t,0)y_0)=A(t)(x(t)\bigoplus y(t))$$
Now the dynamical system make sense on the notion of direct sum.

Good thing about this is that we know that there exists $B(t)$ and $C(t)$ such that
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_e(t,s)=B(t)\Phi_e(t,s)$$
$$\frac{d}{dt}\Phi_u(t,s)=C(t)\Phi_u(t,s)$$
We can further more require that $B(t)y(t)=0$ for all $y(t)\in F(t)$, $C(t)x(t)=0$ for all $x(t)\in E(t)$. We thus have $A(t)=B(t)+C(t)$.

After all those painful set up, we finally obtain an expression similar to $A(t)=\begin{bmatrix} B(t) & 0\\0 & C(t)\end{bmatrix}$ that allows us to work in stable/unsatble component separately, but under the notion of direct sum instead of direct product.

Now good new is that we can work with Lyapunov normal basis (whatever it call) directly instead of needing to worry about the effect of changing of coordinate.